# Wordpress - Output url of my post

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

A question regarding outputting the last piece of the permalink of my (custom post) in Wordpress. Here is the situation:

I am using Fullpage.js to display all my posts of a custom post type. This is working perfectly but now I need to add a data-anchor for every section/post. This data-anchor needs to be the last piece of the specific post's permalink. For example:

localhost/testtheme/projects/painting/

But I need the last piece of this url to be outputed. This would be:

/painting/

I am using the make_link_relative function of Wordpress but this also outputs my /testtheme/projects/ part of the permalink and I don't want this to show up.

I am going to add the snippet code a wrote to beter demonstrate what I mean. Thank you in advance for your help.

Please see line 21 for the data-anchor problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgUow.png)

Kind regards

Comment: Check this out, it might give you what you need. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42124/23672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the post's slug. This can be retrieved from the post object by accessing the 'post_name' attribute, as shown below:

```
<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>
```

Comment: That's what is in my comment above! Worth mentioning, if you're outside the loop you need to include `global $post;` as well so you have access to the post data.

Comment: Thanks Hayward and Andy! This is indeed solving my problem!